# Best way to solve $X^3-X^2-X-1=0$

Tags: cubics

can anyone help me for this cubic equation ?
can be solved without delta method?

$X^3-X^2-X-1=0$

(answer is $\sim 1.8393$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please note, for further reference, the editing I did to your post. $\LaTeX$ is the language of choice for writing math here. Enjoy!

Comment: You can rewrite the equation as $x^3 = x^2 + x + 1$, so $x = \left(x^2 + x + 1\right)^{1/3}$. Write this formula in your calculator, start with $x = 1$, and repeatedly substitute the answer as $x$, and you'll get closer and closer to that answer. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration

Comment: @ReneSchipperus The other two roots are complex.

Comment: Some better methods are bisection method, false position (regula-falsi) method, and Newton-Raphson method. But fixed-point iteration is easy and works in this case.

Comment: Oops made a sign mistake.

Comment: see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciConstant.html by Cardano's method

Comment: Thanks everyone, i think Newton-Raphson method is easier(tnQ @M.Vinay) , fixed-point iteration is good too, but i think Newton method is faster than fixed-point iteration because i don't need very accurate answer ...

Comment: @DEopen Newtons method is going to be the fastest for this kind of problem no matter what precision you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a solution that finds all three roots of the function

$$x^3-x^2-x-1=0$$
Substitute $y=x-\frac{1}{3}$:
$$-\frac{4}{3}-y-(y+\frac{1}{3})^2+(y+\frac{1}{3})^3=0$$
Expanding this gives:
$$y^3-\frac{4}{3}y-\frac{38}{27}=0$$
If $y=\frac{\lambda}{z}+z$ then $z=\frac{1}{2}\left(y+\sqrt{y^2-4\lambda}\right)$
$$-\frac{38}{27}-\frac{4}{3}\left(z+\frac{\lambda}{z}\right)+\left(z+\frac{\lambda}{z}\right)^3=0$$
Multiply both sides by $z^3$
$$z^6+z^4\left(3\lambda-\frac{4}{3}\right)-\frac{38z^3}{27}+z^2\left(3\lambda^2-\frac{4\lambda}{3}\right)+\lambda^3=0$$
Substitute $\lambda=\frac{4}{9}$ and $u=z^3$
$$u^2-\frac{38}{27}u+\frac{64}{729}=0$$
Choose one of the solutions
$$u=\frac{1}{27}(19+3\sqrt{33})$$
Substitute back for $u=z^3$
$$z^3=\frac{1}{27}(19+3\sqrt{33})$$
Solving for $z$
$$z=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}$$
$$z=-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{-19+3\sqrt{33}}$$
$$z=\frac{1}{3}(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}$$
Starting with the first solution, we substitute back for $z=\frac{y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{y^2-\frac{16}{9}}$ 
Solving this for $y$ gives
$$y=\frac{4}{3\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}}+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}$$
Substitute back for $y=x-\frac{1}{3}$
$$x=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4}{3\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}}+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}$$
This is the first solution for $x$, going on to the second solution
$$z=-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{-19-3\sqrt{33}}$$
Substitute back for $z=\frac{y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{y^2-\frac{16}{9}}$
$$\frac{y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{y^2-\frac{16}{9}}=-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{-19-3\sqrt{33}}$$
Solve for $y$
$$y=\frac{4(-1)^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{-19-3\sqrt{33}}$$
Substitute back for $y=x-\frac{1}{3}$
$$x=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4(-1)^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{-19-3\sqrt{33}}$$
Here's the second solution
$$z=\frac{1}{3}(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}$$
For the last solution we substitute back for $z=\frac{y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{y^2-\frac{16}{9}}$
$$\frac{y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{y^2-\frac{16}{9}}=\frac{1}{3}(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}$$
Solve the equation for $y$
$$y=\frac{(-1)^{2/3}}{3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1}{19+3\sqrt{33}}}$$
Substitute back for $x=y-\frac{1}{3}$
$$x=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{(-1)^{2/3}}{3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1}{19+3\sqrt{33}}}$$
I have collected the 3 solutions that I found above here.
$$x=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4}{3\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}}+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}\approx1.83928675521416113255$$
$$x=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4(-1)^{2/3}}{3\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{-19-3\sqrt{33}}\approx-0.41964-0.60629i$$
$$x=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{(-1)^{2/3}}{3}\sqrt[3]{19+3\sqrt{33}}-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-1}{19+3\sqrt{33}}}\approx-0.41964+0.60629i$$

Answer (score 5):

@Darksonn 's answer certainly works, but if you only want the positive real solution, there is a "cubic formula" that is reasonably useful in this case.

> Theorem: If the cubic equation
>   $$X^3 + pX + q$$
>   ($p, q$ real) satisfies 
>   $$\frac{p^3}{27} + \frac{q^2}{4} \geq 0,$$
>   then a solution to the cubic equation is 
>   $$X = \sqrt[3]{- \frac{q}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{p^3}{27} + \frac{q^2}{4}}} + \sqrt[3]{- \frac{q}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{p^3}{27} + \frac{q^2}{4}}}.$$

This is the Cardano-Tartaglia Formula.

In our case, we take @Darksonn 's $y$-substitution $\displaystyle y = x - \frac{1}{3}$ and get

$$y^3 - \frac{4}{3}y - \frac{38}{27} =0.$$

So $p = \displaystyle - \frac{4}{3}$, $q = \displaystyle - \frac{38}{27}$; one may check that in this case, 
$$ \frac{p^3}{27} + \frac{q^2}{4} = \frac{- 64 \cdot 4 + 38^2}{27^2 \cdot 4} = \frac{297}{27^2}, \quad -\frac{q}{2} = \frac{19}{27},$$
so that the answer becomes
\begin{align}
y &= \sqrt[3]{\frac{19}{27} + \sqrt{\frac{297}{27^2}}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{19}{27} - \sqrt{\frac{297}{27^2}}}\\
& = \sqrt[3]{\frac{19 + \sqrt{297}}{27}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{19 - \sqrt{297}}{27}} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{19 + 3\sqrt{33}} +  \sqrt[3]{19 - 3\sqrt{33}} \right).
\end{align}

Since $\displaystyle y = x -  \frac{1}{3}$,  $\displaystyle x = y +  \frac{1}{3}$, and we get
$$x = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{19 + 3\sqrt{33}} +  \sqrt[3]{19 - 3\sqrt{33}} \right).$$

---

To see that our answer matches @Darksonn 's, note that the terms not already matching are $\sqrt[3]{19 - 3\sqrt{33}}$ on the one side and $\displaystyle \frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{19 + 3 \sqrt{33}}}$ on the other side.  To see this equality, note that for all positive $a, b$, 
$$a - b = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a + b}$$
and letting $a = 19$,   $b = 3 \sqrt{33}$, we get
$$19 - 3 \sqrt{33} = \frac{64}{19 + 3 \sqrt{33}}$$
Taking the cube root of both sides, we're done.

---

If you wish to handle the case where the discriminant 
$$\frac{p^3}{27} + \frac{q^2}{4}$$ is negative, or to understand the shortcomings of the above formula, I strongly recommend looking at Lecture 4, "Equations of Degree Three and Four," in Fuchs and Tabachnikov, *Mathematical Omnibus* [Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, 2007].  It is a good "elementary" explanation of what is going on.

Yet other good methods are mentioned in the answers to the similar problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612765/find-roots-of-the-cubic-equation-x3-x2-3-0-without-using-calculator?rq=1 .