# Tilings of 1*n rectangle.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, tiling

The question:
How many ways are there to tile a $1*7$ rectangle with tiles of size $1*1,1*2,1*3$.

My attempt:
Now, the required recurrence would be:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$$
Where $a_n$ is the number of tilings if a $1*n$ rectangle. This is the general case, so I hoped to get the case where $n=7$ from this.

Using $A(x)$ as the Generating function for this recurrence, I end up with:
$$A(x)= \frac 1 {1-x-x^2-x^3}$$.

I'll certainly find the answer for $n=7$ by using the recurrence directly. But if you help solve it for the general case, I'll be extremely happy and grateful.

How do I proceed further? Please answer as soon as possible. Thank you all!!!

Comment: In your first display equation, the middle subscript should be $n-2$  Now you need to expand $A(x)$ in positive powers of $x$ and find the coefficient of $x^7$

Comment: You don't need the generating function, just use your recursion to find the the first few values of $a_n$ similar to how you find Fibonacci values.

Comment: Your question seems a bit muddled.  You say you can use the recursion to solve $n=7$, but instead you want to solve the general case and then apply it to $n=7$?  But why?  Binet’s formula for Fibonacci numbers is already somewhat messy to evaluate, and this recurrence is cubic so it will look 5 times more uglier :).  What’s the benefit?

Comment: Just wanted to see a closed form for this... It's the only wish in my life...

Comment: @Sen47 In that case titling your question “Tilings of 1*7 rectangle” seems like a very indirect way of indicating your wish!

Comment: @ErickWong Edited it sir!

Comment: Wolfram is enough to give the general solution to the recurrence: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+recurrence+a%28n%29+%3D+a%28n-1%29+%2B+a%28n-2%29+%2B+a%28n-3%29.  Have fun matching the coefficients to the initial conditions!

Comment: Well, something is better than nothing! Thanks sir!

Answer (score 2):

For general case, you need to find the roots of this cubic equation $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ using a computer or using this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/819749. Now, general formula for $a_n$ is
$$a_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n+C\gamma^n$$
Now, use initial conditions $$a_1=1$$
$$a_2=2$$
$$a_3=4$$
to find coefficients $A,B$ and $C$ to proceed.

For this particular problem, just use this recursion again and again.
$$a_7=a_6+a_5+a_4$$
$$=2a_5+2a_4+a_3$$
$$=4a_4+3a_3+2a_2$$
$$=7a_3+6a_2+4a_1$$
$$=28+12+4=44$$

Comment: The coefficients of $a_i$ in your last two equations are wrong.  For instance the $2a_5$ contributes $2a_2$ to the next now, not $a_2$.

Comment: @ErickWong, yeah, corrected now. Thanks